# Is it possible to use Hamming distance to find k-Nearest neighbors in 3D point cloud data?

Tags: statistics, distance, point, nearest-neighbor, hamming-distance

I am working on an approximate implementation of the k-nearest neighbors algorithm. I have 3D point cloud data, with x,y,z coordinate values restricted between -1 and 1. Let's say I have a query point and would like to find its k nearest neighbors. Is it possible to do so by calculating the Hamming distances between the reference set points and the query point and using the minimum K values that I get from it? If so, do I need to create hash tables for my data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure does it mean you have at most 8 clusters standing for each combination of x, y, z (vertices of a cube) ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I have unordered data in the form of points. Which clusters are you referring to?

Comment: 3 coordinates with value that can be either -1 or 1. That makes 8 possible combinations. Hamming distance is constrained from 0 to 3. If you have 9 points there is at least two equals (pigeon hole). Could you post a sample of your dataset (not a screenshot, copy paste it in a correct format) and explain how you compute hamming distance on two points.